# Hide FooterTemplate for Asp repeater

Tags: asp.net, controls

I need advices! So I have a custom repeater where I write the footer in the Custom control here is the code :

```
 [ParseChildren(true)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomRepeater runat=server></{0}:CustomRepeater>")]
public class CustomRepeater : Repeater
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty),
     TemplateContainer(typeof(GuessFooterTemplate))]                       
    private ITemplate FooterTemp {get; set;}

    protected override void InitializeItem(RepeaterItem item)
    {
        base.InitializeItem(item);
        FooterTemp = new GFooterTemplate();
        this.FooterTemplate = FooterTemp;                                     
    }


    //Here I try to hide the footer template
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public override ITemplate FooterTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.FooterTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            base.FooterTemplate = value;
        }
    }


}

internal class GFooterTemplate : ITemplate
{
    PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();
    public void InstantiateIn(Control Container)
    {
        ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Test for Footertemplate"));
        Container.Controls.Add(ph);
    }

}
```

So as the footer is writing programmatically, I would like to hide the FooterTemplate for somebody who use the custom repeater.. I was thinking `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]` will do that but apparently not.. Have somebody an idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the users of your `CustomRepeater` to be able to modify the `FooterTemplate`...

I see 2 possible solutions:

Use the [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) modifier on your property to completely redefine it:

```
private new ITemplate FooterTemplate  
{  
  get { return base.FooterTemplate; }  
  set { base.FooterTemplate = value; }  
}
```

Or modify the setter to do nothing, thus preventing the modification:

```
public override ITemplate FooterTemplate
{
  get
  {
    return base.FooterTemplate;
  }
  set
  {
    /* base.FooterTemplate = value; */
  }
}
```

HTH